# Issues with Maven and Android project : transitive dependencies, compilation time and IDEA integration

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, dependency-management

I have an Android project which (unfortunately) uses Maven as a building manager. The thing is that I have a lot of standard java .jar dependencies.

The first issue I am facing is the following :

1) These jar have other dependencies, and sometimes are redundant. The problem is that the removeDuplicates functionality of the android-maven-plugin does not seem to work as intended and I encounter the classic "multiple dex files define class X". I have resolved this issue by excluding the redundant dependencies one by one, which is very tedious and provides me with a pom which can only be qualified as disgusting. So here is my question : is there any way to easily manage transitive dependencies with android-maven-plugin and avoid the "class defined in multiple dex files" error ? Does Gradle handle this kind of stuff in a better way ?  Or am I doomed to use "*" in every dependency exclusions and basically remove the transitive dependency feature from Maven ?

The second issue is about compilation time and the behavior of IDEA when using Maven dependencies in an Android project :

2) First, having to dex that many dependencies is obviously very time consuming. Is there any way to avoid pre-dexing all the jars everytime ? If I understand things correctly, if the jar does not change between 2 builds, then it should not be dexed again. I guess it is because I call mvn clean everytime, however if I do not the "class defined in multiple dex files" error shows up again. The temporary workaround for me was to adequatly declare dependencies in my pom using Maven and use the "Make" function of IDEA, which I guess calls the android tools and build the stuff appropriately. It worked for some time, and it was actually great. The pre-dexing worked as I expected and did not re-dex everything at each compile command. However, I hit the same wall all over again, the "Make" command produces "class defined in multiple dex files", I guess that removing duplicates here does not work either (**just in case I was not clear, the same project, with the same pom, builds successfully with Maven but encounters the error when using "Make"**).

Basically, what I really would like is to declare and manage my dependencies using Maven (actually I do not really have a choice in the matter) and build by calling "Make" in IDEA. The ideal case would be to have the same behavior as "Make" when invoking "mvn clean install". Just in case, I would like to point out the fact that using parallel building is a noticeable improvement but it is quite far from what I would expect.